# How to render twig template in module?

Tags: theming

I'm adding some FB functionality for Drupal 8. Now I'm trying to add FB like button for articles.

I have a twig template **fblikebutton.html.twig**, which looks like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={{ link }}&amp;width&amp;layout={{ layout }}&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces={{ show_faces }}&amp;share={{ share }}&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to bind it somehow with my **fblikebutton.module** file:

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_node_view();
*/

function fblikebutton_node_view(&$build, $node, $display, $type, $lang)
{
  $build['fblikebutton'] = [
    '#theme' => 'fblikebutton',
    '#link' => 'http://example.com/',
    '#layout' => 'standart',
    '#show_faces' => 'false',
    '#share' => false,
    '#weight' => 100, 
  ];
}

/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function fblikebutton_theme() {
  return [
    'fblikebutton' => [
      'variables' => [
        'link' => NULL,
        'layout' => NULL,
        'share' => NULL,
        'show_faces' => NULL,
      ],
      'template' => 'fblikebutton_link',
    ],
  ];
}
```

I feel I'm doing something wrong and would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Sorry, it actually works.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Maybe you should consider answering your own question with regards to how and why it works for future reference, or maybe remove your question alltogether.

Comment: I don't see how it would work, your `template` line (which is optional now by the way - https://www.drupal.org/node/2231673) doesn't match up with your template name. fblikebutton_link vs. fblikebutton. I think it would work once you remove the `template` line though.